# Fetching Previous Member while using order function in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a mdx query which returns  "productCode" and "Product share of total Sales" as a result.Also i need that query be sorted on "Product share of total Sales" (Decs)
So I came up with following MDX Query

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Contribution] AS
     Format(
           IIF(
              IsEmpty([Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]),
              0,
              [Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]
              )/
           [Measures].[SumTotalPayable] 
           )
SELECT  
      {[Measures].[Contribution]} 
   ON COLUMNS,
      Order(
           [DIMProduct].[ProductCode].[ProductCode].AllMEMBERS,
           [Measures].[Contribution],
           BDESC
           ) 
   ON ROWS 
FROM [Model] }
```

the problem is when i also want to have Previous Contribution for each productcode 
i wrote down somthing like this :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Contribution] AS
Format(iif(IsEmpty([Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]),0,[Measures]     [Detail_Net_Sales])/[Measures].[SumTotalPayable] )
MEMBER [Measures].[test]
AS

([Measures].[Contribution], [DIMProduct].[ProductCode].CurrentMember.PrevMember)

SELECT  { [Measures].[Contribution] ,[Measures].[test]} ON COLUMNS
, Order([DIMProduct].[ProductCode].[ProductCode].AllMEMBERS ,[Measures].    [Contribution],BDESC)ON ROWS 
FROM [Model]
```

but the above code will return previous Contribution without desire order.
do you have any idea how  can i fix this?

**Edit :**
I want to have the Contribution of the previous row base on my sort and also have the test measure base on my prior sort,like the below table:

```
ProductCode Contribution Test                       
----------- ------------ ----                                            
123          17.56       null
332          17.30       17.56
245          16          17.30
656          15.90       16
```

but what i get is  like this :

```
ProductCode Contribution Test                       
----------- ------------ ----                                            
123          17.56       17.30
332          17.30       16
245          16          Null
656          15.90       17.30
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `previous Contribution`? The contribution of the product with the product code before that of the current product? The contribution of the same product in the previous month or previous year? The contribution of the product in the row above the current one?

Do I understand you correctly that the sorting of the rows shown is as desired, and your problem is that the `test` measure shows he wrong result? Or does your question mean that you want to sort on measure `test` instead of `contribution`?

Comment: I've edited my post to answer your question,Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Contribution] AS
     Format(
           IIF(
              IsEmpty([Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]),
              0,
              [Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]
              )/
           [Measures].[SumTotalPayable] 
           )
     SET SortedProducts AS
     Order(
           [DIMProduct].[ProductCode].[ProductCode].AllMEMBERS,
           [Measures].[Contribution],
           BDESC
           ) 
     MEMBER [Measures].[PrevContribution] AS
     (SortedProducts.Item(
           Rank([DIMProduct].[ProductCode].CurrentMember, SortedProducts) - 2)
           .Item(0), 
     [Measures].[Contribution]) 
SELECT  
      {[Measures].[Contribution], [Measures].[PrevContribution]} 
   ON COLUMNS,
      SortedProducts
   ON ROWS 
FROM [Model] }
```

Your definition of the `test` measure uses the order of members as defined in the cube (alphabetically, if you did not define a custom order). But you need the order by `Contribution`, so I defined that as a named set containing the members in this order. Then I mis-used the `Rank` function which gives you the position of a tuple in a set. As the rank of the first member is 1, and I use the `Item` function to get a tuple within the set - which starts numbering the tuples with zero -, and we have to go one member back, you need the `- 2`, and finally, we need another `Item(0)` to get a member from the tuple.